# how to validate data inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

here i try to get data using REST METHOD,so here i use a ajax call for it,my work is done but problem is I need to validate "data" inside the ajax call ,how i do it?because if there are no any data from the URL it give error .i need to fix it.

```js
$.ajax({  
    'url': url_for_check_available_updates_tab7,
    'type':'POST',
    'async': false,
    'success':function(data){
        
        d = data.getElementsByTagName("col")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        
        
    },
    error: function() {             
        $('#no_update').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please add more information.Where you posting your data ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha okay thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(null !== data && typeof data !== "undefined" && data.getElementsByTagName("col").length !== 0)
```